# jQuery - .each() the inputs value to compare it all

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve something like when you put your mouse over one text field it will highlights all the input fields with the same values. I did it with class but I'm having a hard time with input's value.

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' class='value1' value='sample1'>
<input type='text' class='value2' value='sample2'>
<input type='text' class='value2' value='sample3'>
<input type='text' class='value2' value='sample4'>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input.value2").each(function(){
    $("input.value2").on('mouseover',function(){
        $("input.value2").css('background-color','yellow');
    });
    $("input.value2").on('mouseout',function(){
        $("input.value2").css('background-color','#fff');
    });
});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L53du3km/)

Try to put the mouse to 2nd text field.

Comment: Be clear about your question. Do you want to have the same functionality for the content of text field?

Comment: Yes I want the same functionality like what I example but with the same input's value, not with the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a common class for all input, in example I have use `myClass`
2. Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find input with same value.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.myClass").on('mouseover', function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $("input.myClass").filter(function(){
            return value == this.value;
        }).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $("input.myClass").filter(function(){
            return value == this.value;
        }).css('background-color', '#fff');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='myClass' value='sample1'>
<input type='text' class='myClass' value='sample2'>
<input type='text' class='myClass' value='sample3'>
<input type='text' class='myClass' value='sample4'>
```

Comment: both paul roub and satpal answers solved my problem i just vote this one because it was posted first. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to find only the matching elements whose value is the same as the hovered field:

```
$("input.value2").on('mouseover',function(){
  // store the value of the element that was hovered
  var val = this.value;

  $('input.value2').filter(

    // this function will be called once for each input.value2 element
    // filter will return a list of *only* those elements where this
    // function returns true

    function() { 
      // 
      return this.value == val; 
    }

  ).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

```js
$("input.value2").on('mouseover', function() {
  var val = this.value;

  $('input.value2').filter(
    function() {
      return this.value == val;
    }
  ).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});

$("input.value2").on('mouseout', function() {
  $("input.value2").css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='value1' value='sample1'>
<input type='text' class='value2' value='sample2'>
<input type='text' class='value2' value='sample2'>
<input type='text' class='value2' value='sample4'>
```